# Print the value based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print a value based on selected value without submit and without reload the page

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#select").on("change", function() {
  //alert("Welcome to " + $(this).val());
    $('#text').html("Welcome to " + $(':selected').text())
}).trigger('change'); //trigger on page load

</script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="text"></div>
```

I want to print if selected value is audi then it will print Welcome to Aundi like wise without reload and without submit

Comment: You may used Ajax for this

Comment: How to use i am new from ajax can you please suggest me

Comment: @MuhammadArif, just to display _Welcome_, I  don't think OP will need `ajax`

Comment: I am going to use popup so i need without seletct Like Flipkart EMI Option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :-

```js
$("#select").on("change", function(){
   $('#text').html("Welcome to " + $(':selected').text())
}).trigger('change'); //trigger on page load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: OP is expecting _Welcome to Aundi_...Just joking :P

Comment: @Kartikeya i want to display bottom not a popup

Comment: @LearningMagento...just take a empty div in your markup and set its html with `.html()`.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla `$(':selected').text()` would be better.

Comment: Check my updaed question it's not printing

Comment: @LearningMagento...you have changed the context of your question completely...pasted my answer in the question...anyways...just see the browser console  i think you have not included jquery file,modify your html also..give id to select and add a empty div as shown in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use angular JS 

see following plunker for reference

your HTML
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheckbox" ng-change="cbSelected()" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="text1" readonly />
  <input type="text" ng-model="text2" ng-readonly="!myCheckbox" />
  <h3> {{text2}}</h3>
</body>

</html> 


App.js
ngular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.text1 = 'some-text';

  $scope.cbSelected = function() {
      if ($scope.myCheckbox) {  // when checked
        $scope.text2 = angular.copy($scope.text1);
      } else {
        $scope.text2 = "";
      }
  };
});

Customise according to your requirement 
http://plnkr.co/edit/vURMjLxArLsRSKZj5o9q?p=preview
```

Comment: @RayonDabre This person is trying to migrate the current project to angular based.

Comment: @rayon sorry , didnt fork earlier plunker so old version got reflected ,
as he didnt mentioned what technology he want i posted angular solution

Comment: @aadesh Boss! don't be sorry. this is not angular post. think.

Comment: @aadesh _he didnt mentioned what technology he want_ check the tags below the post dude.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select[name=nameOfSelect]').change(function() { alert("welcome to " + $(this).val()); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="nameOfSelect"> 
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Use .val to get the value of the selected option. See below,

`<select>` would be

```
<select name="nameOfSelect">
```

then use.

```
$('select[name=nameOfSelect]').change(function() { alert("welcome to " + $(this).val()); });
```

hope it helps..:)